# Installing foundation 3 with scss

Tags: sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I am trying to download and use foundation 3 with compass and scss, but I can't understand the instructions that is on the following page:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compass.php

It says that i have to write the following "[sudo] gem install zurb-foundation". But where, in my browser, in my css document, in my php documents?

I now that this might sound stupid, but I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. It seems that you need to install ruby. Here is how I did it:

1. Go to http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
2. Download the latest version of the rubyinstallers (for me it was Ruby 2.0.0-p0)
3. Run the .exe installer when it has downloaded (check all 3 boxes during the install)
4. After the install is finished, find the rubycatalog in your startmenu (on your computer)
5. Klick on "start commandprompt with ruby"
6. in the commandprompt, type "gem update zurb-foundation" leave out the [sudo] part, it gave me an error, don't know what it is fore anyway.
7. foundation with sass is installing :)